# Oracle Database 12c tnsnames.ora file

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I am new in Oracle 12c. In installation steps I need to add service orclpdb in tnsnames.ora file. Why I need to add this service?

```
ORCLPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Do you mean: Why do I have to put this text in `tnsnames.ora` file?

Comment: Where did you get the installation steps from? Could you share it ?  Please append a link to it to the question.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit Yes I mean that "Why do I have to put this text in tnsnames.ora file?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no need for any `tnsnames.ora` file.

However, writing `sqlplus @ORCLPDB` is just much simpler than writing `sqlplus @(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb)))` for example. `tnsnames.ora` provides easy alias instead of using the full name which is rather complicated.